# How to make a Firebase rule making sure you can only enter certain things in a field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I'm using Firebase to run a message board in which every post must first be approved by a moderator.

Thus, a post can have one of three "statuses":

- Unreviewed
- Approved
- Rejected

The only way I've found to make this rule is like so:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "posts": {
            ".write": "newData.child('status').val() == 'unreviewed' || newData.child('status').val() == 'approved' || newData.child('status').val() == 'rejected"
        }
    }
}
```

This seems very inefficient and not DRY. Is there another way of making sure a field's value is always one of a few values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security rules language is a limited subset of JavaScript, so you cannot completely clean up the repetitions... But you can certainly shorten it a little, while making it less error-prone too.

---

### Sidenote: Avoiding the security problem

One of the issues with your attempt is that you use `.write` rules to validate the data. These rules **are completely ignored** if any parent or higher rule grants write access to this subtree.

But fret not, you just have to move data validation to `.validate` rules instead. They are always evaluated and enforced on write operations – with the only exception being the admin users.

---

### Cleaning up the rules

Restructuring the rules to *follow* your expected schema helps a great deal in improving readability, even if the character count is not much less.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$postId": {  // (1)
        ".validate": "newData.child('status').exists()", // (2)

        "status": {
          ".validate": "newData.val() == 'unreviewed' || newData.val() == 'approved' || newData.val() == 'rejected"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. I added this level because I *assumed* you want to store a list of posts, not just a single post under `/posts`.
2. Listing the required child nodes (or "fields") should be done on the post. The validation rule for `status` would be ignored otherwise if it is not set in the new posts.

---

Also, take a look at the [Bolt compiler](https://github.com/firebase/bolt). It helps you DRY out the security rules and generate the validation rules.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I hadn't heard of Bolt before.